# Immutable vs mutable

Tags: ruby

I do not understand what is going on in the line
`print buggy_logger << "\n" # <- This insertion is the bug.`
Why is that the variable status changes when the above line is called? 
I am following this website http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/

```
status = "peace"

 buggy_logger = status

 print "Status: "
 print buggy_logger << "\n" # <- This insertion is the bug.

def launch_nukes?(status)
  unless status == 'peace'
   return true
  else
return false
 end
end

print "Nukes Launched: #{launch_nukes?(status)}\n"
```

OUTPUT IS:

## => Status: peace

## => Nukes Launched: true

Comment: Because you're adding a newline to the string?

Comment: [`String#<<`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) (aka concat) *mutates* the original string object (which was created by "peace"). I recommend *not* using mutations for strings, but instead use `+` instead of `<<` here.

Comment: Thanks  user2864740. I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is "why does the variable change?"

The answer is because `buggy_logger` holds a reference to `status`. Easily proven by inspecting the `object_id`.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = "hi"
=> "hi"
irb(main):002:0> a.object_id
=> 24088560
irb(main):003:0> b = a
=> "hi"
irb(main):004:0> b.object_id
=> 24088560
irb(main):005:0>
```

To create a copy use `+` or any non-mutating operator. Don't use `<<`.

```
irb(main):010:0> c = a + " guys"
=> "hi guys"
irb(main):011:0> c.object_id
=> 26523040
irb(main):012:0>
```

Comment: Or .. just use the correct non-mutating operator (ie. not `<<`).

Comment: @user2864740 You can do this, but it's dangerous to 'guess' at which operators mutate and which don't. It's safer to just create a new object from the get go.

Comment: @Rots What are you recommending OP do? Use `String.new` and `<<`? I'd fail that in a code review.

Comment: @MarkThomas You're right! I'm going to change the second section of my answer to match user2864740's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Since `status = "peace"` is a string, when `buggy_logger << "\n"` is ran, it's updating the string of `buggy_logger` (and subsequently, `status`) to be "peace\n"

Therefore, when the method is ran, it returns true because `status != "peace"` anymore.

Now, if in the beginning you used a symbol `status = :peace`, it would not be able to be altered with the "\n" appendage. Therefore, the method would return false because `status == :peace`

**Symbol version:**

```
status = :peace

 buggy_logger = status

 print "Status: "
 #print buggy_logger << "\n" # This is no longer possible. It will cause an error

def launch_nukes?(status)
  unless status == :peace
   return true
  else
return false
 end
end

print "Nukes Launched: #{launch_nukes?(status)}\n"  # <- Returns FALSE
```

Comment: There is no "symbol version", because symbols cannot be mutated (and furthermore, have no `#<<`).

Comment: I think he's recommending enumeration of statuses, which is a good idea. It can be done as symbols, ActiveRecord enums, or a custom class.

Comment: The "symbol version" is just showing the same example and how the (accidental) mutation effect can be avoided by using symbols. The article in which this example is used is contrasting the two.